# can't pass parameter from view to controller

Tags: zend-framework

Hi all I am currently working with zend 2.3. and while listing students I am trying to make link that allows to show detales about selected person. My problem is that I can't pass selected id to the action in module's controller. Here is my view's code that coresponds to link:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $this->url('admin' ,
             array( 'controller'=>'Admin', 'action'=>'viewstudent', 'ID' => $student->ID))."/admin/viewstudent";?>">detales</a>
```

and the action in controller

```
public function viewstudentAction ()
{

    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('ID', 0);
echo $id;
//echo var_dump($id);
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'students' => $this->getStudentTable()->viewstudent($id),
    ));
}
```

Then I `var_dump $id` variable it shows 0 So what is the correct way to do this?

I have edited the a href's code like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('admin/default' ,
             array( 'controller'=>'Admin', 'action'=>'viewstudent', 'id' => $student->ID));?>">Просмотр</a>
```

and it resolves to this:

```
<a href="/disability/public/admin/Admin/viewstudent">Просмотр</a>
```

url is

http://localhost:8080/disability/public/admin/Admin/viewstudent

The url is

http://localhost:8080/disability/public/admin/Admin/viewstudent

Problem is the same id didn't pass

Comment: Do you have an example of the routing set up?
Looking at that, the URL would result in something similar to /Admin/viewstudent/[ID]/admin/viewstudent ?

Comment: @Rachel Thanks for comment I have edited a a href part Problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the problem. I passed the parameter using query here is how it looks in view file

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('admin/default', 
   array('controller' => 'Admin',  
           'action'=>'viewstudent' 
     ), 
     array('query' =>  
         array('id' => $student->ID) 
     ) 
 ); 
?>">view</a>
```

And then using $this->params retrieve it in my controller file

```
  $id =  $this->params()->fromQuery('id');
```